# Unity Game Not Responding To Any Click/Touch on Android Mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play

It weird i didn't change nothing everything was working before when i uploaded many versions of my game to do some tests on google play but suddenly GUI buttons or any click on mobile screen are not responding in the newest versions i built without doing any modification to the code or canvas , any idea ? (they work on editor)

Logcat :

```
08-04 03:03:18.089: I/Unity(29886): SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 4, Memory = 880mb
08-04 03:03:18.089: I/Unity(29886): SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 0xf), 0 little (mask: 0x0)
08-04 03:03:18.089: I/Unity(29886): ApplicationInfo com.Company.GameName version 0.96 build c1ae84fd-65e9-403e-9d37-b13a947efd2e
08-04 03:03:18.089: I/Unity(29886): Built from '2018.3/staging' branch, Version '2018.3.3f1 (393bae82dbb8)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
08-04 03:03:18.659: D/Unity(29886):  GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query
08-04 03:03:19.589: W/Unity(29886): OnLevelWasLoaded was found on Reporter
08-04 03:03:19.589: W/Unity(29886): This message has been deprecated and will be removed in a later version of Unity.
08-04 03:03:19.589: W/Unity(29886): Add a delegate to SceneManager.sceneLoaded instead to get notifications after scene loading has completed
08-04 03:03:19.589: W/Unity(29886):  
08-04 03:03:19.589: W/Unity(29886): (Filename:  Line: 356)
08-04 03:03:24.739: E/Unity(29886): AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener
08-04 03:03:24.739: E/Unity(29886): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener
08-04 03:03:24.739: E/Unity(29886):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-04 03:03:24.739: E/Unity(29886):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
08-04 03:03:24.739: E/Unity(29886):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:272)
08-04 03:03:24.739: E/Unity(29886):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
08-04 03:03:24.739: E/Unity(29886):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
08-04 03:03:24.739: E/Unity(29886):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source)
08-04 03:03:24.739: E/Unity(29886):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:211)
08-04 03:03:24.739: E/Unity(29886):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
08-04 03:03:24.739: E/Unity(29886):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)
08-04 03:03:24.739: E/Unity(29886): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Company.GameName-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Company.GameName-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /sys
```

i'm not sure this error is related to that problem Admob ads were working before

Comment: Have you tried creating a new Canvas/EventSystem, and seeing if that works?  Usually when Unity UI breaks it's due to a lack of EventSystem, or an invisible UI element blocking others.  If your buttons work in the editor, it's also possible that some code you're executing on the button fails on your mobile device.  I would also recommend checking LogCat to see if Unity throws any errors when running on Android.  Without any other information (like error messages), I'm afraid those are the only ideas I have - good luck!

Comment: thanks for your reply actually i have another logcat program with my game files the one from asset store where u need to touch screen in th opposite of clock move circle and it will open the errors and messages but when i tried that it didn't open so not just buttons any touch  or click on screen is not responding

Comment: It seems like something is wrong with the Java APIs you are using in your project.  From experience, I can say that using Admob/monetization services is a library-dependency nightmare.  Your build is probably missing an API (which is needed only for Android, thus, your project still works in the editor) necessary for some of those Google-related functions.  I'd have a look at [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1347425/problem-with-adds-play-services.html) and [this one](https://forum.unity.com/threads/google-admob-poblem.469725/) - the solutions found here might be of help.

Comment: @Douglas Dwyer actually for the solution was to upgrade unity to the newest version 2019.2.0f1 , and for the error is to do a Force Resolve

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bug to solve the problem i upgraded unity to the latest version 2019.2.0f1 and now mobile screen respond to my clicks , for the error i did a Force Resolve